# Piping Get-mailbox -filter into Get-mailboxstatistics -filter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to filter a list with two commands - 
Filter by Attribute then filter by "not disconnected" and "logged in in the last 90 days."
Trying something like this, but it's not working.

> get-mailbox -filter 'ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq $null'|
>   Get-MailboxStatistics -filter {DisconnectDate -eq $null -and
>   LastLogonTime -gt (get-date).adddays(-90)}

When I run;

> get-mailbox -filter 'ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq $null' |
>   Get-MailboxStatistics

I get the first part of the results with the info I'm looking for - I just can't filter this list further. ie adding *-filter* does not work.

The result is:

[image: Results of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the best solution to your problem is to filter via where-object as stated earlier.

The below should work out for you, it has not been tested but should be correct.

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter 'ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq $null' | Get-MailboxStatistics | where {$_.DisconnectDate -eq $null -and $_.LastLogonTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}
```

Comment: Yes!  Funny, 5 mins after I posted I stumbled into the same code, So thanks this works!

Answer (score 0):

Technet documentation specifies that filters must be done using single quotes, not curly braces.

```
-Filter 'DisconnectDate -ne $null'
```

Is the example given here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124612(v=exchg.160).aspx

I've run into this issue before when filtering AD users. I have to assume that they changed their standard at some time during the past.

If you don't have success with this, you can try using where-object to filter to the right... i.e.:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics | ?{$_.DisconnectDate -ne $null}
```

Obviously use the former if it works.